# Create interface with what type of smart pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have some code that produces widgets like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget1> Widget1::Create()
std::unique_ptr<Widget2> Widget2::Create()
```

Now I have another piece of code that needs to use `Widget1` and `Widget2`. I'd like for it to have a similar interface, but take the widgets as inputs.

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget3> Widget3::Create(<?> Widget1, <?> Widget2)
```

Internally, `Widget3` should contain a reference, such as

```
class Widget3
{
public:
   std::unique_ptr<Widget3> Create(<?> Widget1, <?> Widget2)
   {
      _widget1 = Widget1;
      _widget2 = Widget2;
   }
   void doSomething()
   {
      std::cout << _widget1->hello() << _widget2->hello();
   }
private:
   <?> _widget1, _widget2
};
```

Now I've thought about using a `std::shared_ptr` for `<?>` because this appears to be the most sane. However... I'm confused on *how* I should pass it in?

Thoughts?

Comment: You should read http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Comment: I read this, but most of it appeared to be specific to functions with a limited lifetime. I think the herbsutter article in addition to @Richard Hodges response below, really go well together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is 'separation of concerns'.

The *lifetime* of an object is a separate concern to its *implementation*.

`shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` control *lifetime*. Widget*n* objects *do* things.

If you respect that separation of concerns in your code design, your life will be a happy one, your programs will never go wrong and your colleagues will love you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct Widget1 {
    std::string hello() { return "widget1"; }
};

struct Widget2 {
    std::string hello() { return "widget2"; }
};

struct Widget3 {
    // Widget3 objects share their components. This is now documented in the interface here...
    Widget3(std::shared_ptr<Widget1> widget1, std::shared_ptr<Widget2> widget2)
    : _widget1(std::move(widget1))
    , _widget2(std::move(widget2))
    {
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        std::cout << _widget1->hello() << _widget2->hello();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Widget1> _widget1;
    std::shared_ptr<Widget2> _widget2;
};

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    // make a unique Widget3
    auto w1a = make_unique<Widget1>();
    auto w2a = make_unique<Widget2>();
    // note the automatic move-conversion from unique_ptr to shared_ptr
    auto w3a = make_unique<Widget3>(move(w1a), move(w2a));

    // make unique widget3 that uses shared components
    auto w1b = make_shared<Widget1>();
    auto w2b = make_shared<Widget2>();
    auto w3b = make_unique<Widget3>(w1b, w2b);

    // make shared widget3 that shares the same shared components as w3b
    auto w3c = make_shared<Widget3>(w1b, w2b);

    return 0;
}
```

The use of static ::create functions is un-necessary. It enforces a memory model on the creator of your object.

If you want to enforce a memory model (such as always creating a shared pointer), do it privately, using the shared-handle-pimpl idiom:

```
// Widget4 objects have shared-handle semantics.
struct Widget4
{
private:
    struct impl {
        std::string hello() const { return "hello4"; }
    };

public:
    Widget4()
    : _impl { std::make_shared<impl>() }
    {}

    std::string hello() const {
        return _impl->hello();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<impl> _impl;
};
```

Comment: Seriously, thank you! This cleared up everything for me.

Comment: @matt you're welcome. 'separation of concerns' is the single biggest productivity enhancer in computer science. It seems like more work at the start, but it's not. It's a massive time-saver and it makes you look like a pro ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If Widget1 and widget2 are going to exist only as member of widget3  and you don't need to refer those variables later independently you can pass them as value to `Widget3::create()`

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget1> Widget1::Create()// returns a unique_ptr to widget1
std::unique_ptr<Widget2> Widget2::Create()// returns a unique_ptr to widget2

std::unique_ptr<Widget3> Create(std::unique_ptr<Widget1>  Widget1,
                                std::unique_ptr<Widget2>  Widget2)
```

Otherwise if you prefer to keep objects of Widget1 and Widget2 as shared object with  Widget3, use shared_ptr for widget1 and widget2